# What is the most efficient way to remove all the elements of one array from another array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two arrays, array A contains a long list with some elements I want to remove. Array B is the full list of those elements that I wish to remove from array A.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

array_diff is the obvious answer, but since you've asked for the most efficient way, here's a test

```
$big = range(1, 90000);
$remove = range(500, 600);

$ts = microtime(true);
$result = array_diff($big, $remove);
printf("%.2f\n", microtime(true) - $ts);

$ts = microtime(true);
$map = array_flip($remove);
$result = array();
foreach($big as $e)
    if(!isset($map[$e]))
        $result[] = $e;
printf("%.2f\n", microtime(true) - $ts);
```

prints on my machine

```
0.67
0.03
```

So the simple loop with a hash-based lookup is approximately 20 times faster than array_diff.

Comment: I want to object to this answer because of memory usage or some way that array_diff performs the operation better... but I can't think of anything accurate. Kudos, now go tell the php devs to make array_diff faster.

Answer (score 12):

Use [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Answer (score 6):

In the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) it gives for [array_dif()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) this exaple:

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

> Returns an array containing all the
>   entries from array1 that are not
>   present in any of the other arrays.